# Internet connection lost every time computer sleeps or shuts down

Tags: networking, windows-8, router, sleep

I have an ADSL internet connection that works through a modem (actually a router - Aztech ADSL2+ Ethernet Bridge Router DSL-600E). I know that there's a way to put in my username and password to my ISP in the router itself, but my ISP changed the default password to the router's control panel. I'm nervous to reset it just in case there are any important settings they made.

So I made a "connection" (by searching with Window key-S for "Internet" and choosing "connect to the internet") with my username and password info to connect to the ISP, and it connects fine. However, I would like it to automatically connect to that connection automatically whenever I turn on or wake up the computer.

Currently, every time I turn the computer off or sleep it, the connection gets an [error icon](http://www.transcription.co.il/ebay/network_error.png). It's not such a big deal, because I just click on it, and then it comes up with my connection, and I click on that, it verifies the username and password, and I'm connected, but I sleep the computer very often so it gets annoying.

In previous computers with older versions of Windows, I just put the connection in startup to make it run automatically when I turned it on, and I never slept it, but I can't figure out what program to run to make it connect.

When I take the computer to an area that has a wireless connection, then it does connect automatically, the issue is only with wired connections.

Comment: If you are nervous make a backup of the configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound How? I can't log into it at all without the username and password. The only way I can reset it by pressing the reset button on it.

Comment: Call your ISP and ask for the username and password.  But based on your own statements I thought you already knew it " ... with my ISP's username and password info, and it connects fine"

Comment: @Ramhound - I know the username and password to connect to the ISP, not to get into the router's control panel. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: edited the question to make more clear that point

Comment: @Ramhound I think I tried calling once and they weren't willing to give it out. I could try again, though, it probably depends which tech support person you happen to get. I could also try searching around on the Internet to see if anyone's ever figured it out.

Comment: The worst case.  You reset the router and the configuration changes are lost and you have to call them for help.  Honestly without access to the router's configuration page you are stuck without a solution using the router to do what you want.

Comment: I would say reset the router and set it up as new, but is it's a "rental" router then they probably have a legal thing meaning you can't mess with it. [This answer to a similar issue](http://superuser.com/a/579914) looks promising.

Comment: @Jonah It is a rental router. I think getting a new router or taking the risk resetting it is a bit of an overkill for such a small issue. I'm really looking for a way to connect from the commandline or some other way to do it automatically.